# How to get upper and lower value of specific column cell value in datatable using Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable, dataset

I have a data table contains data like below(dtDocument)

```
DocumentID  ProjectID   DocumentTypeID StatusID    StatusReason 
----------- ----------- -------------- ----------- -------------
299         1           1              0           NULL         
300         1           1              35          NULL         
301         1           1              0           NULL         
302         1           1              26          NULL         
303         1           1              27          NULL         
304         1           1              26          NULL         
305         1           1              28          NULL         
306         1           1              27          NULL         
307         1           1              27          NULL         
308         1           1              27          NULL         
309         1           1              27          NULL         
310         1           1              27          NULL
```

Client can send DocumentID based on that documentId i want to fetch that document Previous and next document Id. This can be used for my Next,Previous buttons.

**I want the performance query using Linq(Preferrable)**

Example: If user selects  303 Document and selects Next button it will move to 304 and if user selects Previous button it will move to 302

Comment: What you have tried so far? Btw consider to use BindingSource

Comment: i used sql query for that

Comment: Do you have all data on client side? Is it winforms, or wpf, or asp.net?

Comment: Please add your sql query?

Comment: WCF (Rest service) Mr.lazyberezovsky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var forNext = (from myRow in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                           where myRow.Field<int>("DocumentID") > CurrentID
                           orderby myRow.Field<int>("DocumentID")
                           select myRow).FirstOrDefault();

            var forPrevious = (from myRow in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                               where myRow.Field<int>("DocumentID") < CurrentID
                               orderby myRow.Field<int>("DocumentID") descending
                               select myRow).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var prevID = dtDocument.Where(d => d.DocumentID < selectedID).Max(d => d.DocumentID);
var nextID = dtDocument.Where(d => d.DocumentID > selectedID).Min(d => d.DocumentID);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a variable keeping the current record number and two buttons that will add or subtract from this number and calling the following:

```
public dtDocument GetDocument(int record)
{
    return dtDocument.OrderBy(x=>x.DocumentID).Skip(record - 1).Take(1)
}
```

Comment: I think you should skip `record` and that will work if all documents have  incremental ids starting from 1 without

Comment: No, because for the first record (1) i want to skip 0.

Comment: If you will skip 0, than you will return exactly same document

Comment: The essense in this is that you say fetch me record number X. So if you want the first record (X=1) then you should Skip 0.

Comment: OP wants previous and next documents without knowing their ids. All your code essentially does is `dtDocument.Where(x => x.DocumentId == record)` (btw return type should be IEnumerable)

Comment: No, you get it wrong. I don't use the ID anywhere to filter. I just order by it. Then i get the record which is in the X position no matter what the Id is.

Comment: OK, now I see what you mean. Confusing part is `record` variable - thus OP wants to get documents by currentID, but you are getting by current index instead

Comment: Well, i guess it is better that way, as you don't mind if you have gaps in the ids. But still... it depends on the business rules.